# Is 拝見いたしました an example of 二重敬語?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, keigo

二重敬語 is presumably considered bad style (or simply incorrect).

I hear/read 拝見いたしました all the time. Is it an example of 二重敬語?

I understood 二重敬語 to be a little more complex than "used a polite form more than once in a phrase".

To be a bit more precise, I think that to express a verb in 敬語, one should make the verb polite, but *only once*, so that

> お読みになる

is 敬語, but

> お読みになられる

is 二重敬語.

拝見いたす might be fine, because 拝見 is a (敬語) noun and いたす is a (敬語) verb; or it might be a problem, because 拝見する is a (敬語) form of 見る.

Comment: I imagine it falls into the "慣例として定着している二重敬語の例" section of http://www.levelup99.net/businessmanner/cate3post21.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the title question as a simple yes-no question, the only logical answer would be "Yes, it is."  The phrase clearly uses a [敬語]{けいご} twice,「[拝見]{はいけん}」 and 「いたす」, which  satisfies the definition of [二重敬語]{にじゅうけいご}.

Is the phrase 「拝見いたしました」 "incorrect" then?  According to me, no, it is not.  Why not?  Because it is in such wide use and it just sounds normal and natural if you have a native ear.  It carries none of the "wordiness" (and if I may, "funniness") of some of the other examples of 二重敬語 such as 「お[分]{わ}かりになられる」 and 「お[召]{め}し[上]{あ}がりになられる」.

Comment: I wonder, is this feeling only for 拝見, or is any humble 漢語動詞＋「いたす」 acceptable? (E.g., 頂戴いたす、拝借いたす、etc.)